# ubuntu server nginx not working ufw configured

Tags: nginx, docker, local-area-network

I have fresh installation of Ubuntu server 22.04.
I can't connect to my docker container.
Here is some more information:

`ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
96c1479b1a2c   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   nginx-container
```

`curl localhost` and `curl 192.168.0.134` (from same server)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`curl 192.168.0.134` from device which I use to ssh access:

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.134 port 80 after 25916 ms: Operation timed out
```

same problem on browser (Chrome)

ping from host to server working:

```
ping 192.168.0.134
PING 192.168.0.134 (192.168.0.134): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.134: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.039 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.134: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.225 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.134: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.588 ms
```

Any idea? In my opinion, docker and ufw is configured properly, I hope my router is not blocking anything (host is laptop with wifi, server is connected by cable, ssh working properly so devices have connection probably)

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. Check if there is another firewall involved.

Comment: This is fresh, Ubuntu server. Usually I working with standard Ubuntu desktop and I do not have problem like this. Do You know what could be name of Ubuntu preinstalled firewall?